# Drawing a graph with only cycles of length 5 through 9.

Tags: graph-theory

I'm working my way through [Combinatorics and Graph Theory, 2nd Ed.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387797106), which contains the following exercise:

> Draw a connected graph having at most 10 vertices that has at least one cycle of each length from 5 through 9, but has no cycles of any other length.

I'm stumped as to how to even begin attempting to solve this problem, aside from drawing graphs through trial-and-error. It seems like any graph I draw with a cycle with length of 5 also contains a cycle with $len < 5$.

What is an example of such a graph? How does one approach tackling this sort of challenge?

Comment: Those numbers immediately make the think of the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph) ...

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Draw a cycle of length 9. Can you see how to build a 6-cycle and a 7-cycle with the extra vertex? Now remains to build the 5-cycle and the 8-cycle. You can build the 5-cycle by adding only 1 edge. I hope this can help you without giving you the solution straight away!

Comment: It might help to draw 9 vertices in a circle and place the 10th suggested above outside the circle. Then the remaining edge can be placed 'inside' the circle.

Comment: @copper.hat: I'm wondering how many graphs (up to isomorphism) with these properties exist. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks, @Antoine. I realize now that most of these exercises require prolonged thought. I'll accept your answer once I've used your hint to answer the question. Thanks!